# Print a character in a different color attributes within the same line with ncurses/c++

Tags: c++, linux, colors, attributes, ncurses

I'd like to print a character in a different color (with bold attribute) from the rest of a string using ncurses.
I only get a box shape instead of the colored character.

Compiling with g++:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 print.cpp -lncursesw -o print && ./print
```

The character I'm trying to print in a different color with a bold attribute is `std::string arrow = "\ue0b1";`

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    initscr(); noecho(); cbreak(); curs_set(0);
    if (has_colors()) {
        use_default_colors();
        init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_CYAN);
        init_pair(2, -1, COLOR_WHITE);
        init_pair(3, -1, COLOR_CYAN);
        init_pair(4, COLOR_CYAN, -1);
    }
    int y, x;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, y, x);
    WINDOW *win = newwin(y, x, 0, 0);
    keypad(stdscr, true);
    wrefresh(win);
    refresh();

    std::string home = "home ";
    std::string cmake_str = " cmake";
    std::string arrow = "\ue0b1";
    home += arrow + cmake_str;

    std::size_t pos = 0; 
    int ch;
    while (1) {
        mvwprintw(win, 0, 0, "Press <Esc> to end program.");
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < home.length(); ++i) {
            pos = home.find(arrow);
            if (pos != std::string::npos) {
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                addch(home[i]);
            }
            move(2, i);
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
            addch(home[i]);
            refresh();
            wrefresh(win);
        }
        if ((ch = wgetch(win)) == 27) { break; }
    }
    delwin(win);
    endwin(); 
    return 0;
}
```

The expected result would preferably be like this using ANSI:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string home = "home ";
    std::string cmake_str = " cmake";
    std::string arrow = "\ue0b1";

    std::string fg_cyan = "\033[36m";
    std::string reset = "\033[0m";
    std::string bold = "\033[1m";

    std::cout << home << bold << fg_cyan << arrow << reset << cmake_str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your `arrow` is a UTF-8 encoded string, not a single char.  You need to use `waddch` to output a wide character (curses `chtype` -- probably a `wchar_t`) rather than a `char`.

Comment: typo above -- you need `add_wch` instead of `addch` (not `waddch`)

Comment: that, plus probably some assistance in converting `std::string` to an `wchar_t` values.

Comment: @ChrisDodd  @ThomasDickey I get a comiler error for add_wch: ```use of undeclared identifier 'add_wch'; did you mean 'addch'? ``` I also added ```scrollok(win, true)``` with no effect?

Comment: To get `add_wch`, you need use `#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>` to get the wide-char version of ncurses.  Without it, you can't use non-ascii characters other than the special graphic chars in curses.h